# MATLAB : how to pass the string variable from a function to GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

For example, I have a function called `function1` which has a variable, say `str1` which holds a string.

I have also a GUI created by using MATLAB's `GUIDE` with the tag called `textgui` that has a **static text** tagged `text1`.

How do I pass the string `str1` to the GUI so that when I run the GUI the static text `text1` will show the string of the variable `str1`?

EDIT : `function1` will generate the string `str1` and then call the GUI `textgui` to show the string

EDIT2 : below is the code of `function1` and an image of `textgui`.

```
str1 = 'some text here';
textgui; % runs the GUI
```

[image: below is the image of the GUI <code>textgui</code>.]

what should I do so that when I run `function1`, the static text in the GUI will show as the string which `str1` holds?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the value of `str1`, you just want to update the `String` property of the static text object using this variable.

```
str1 = 'my string';
set(handles.text1, 'String', str1)
```

If your `function1` isn't a callback of your GUI, you can always use `findall` to find the handle to the static text object and set it that way.

```
str1 = 'my string';
set(findall(0, 'tag', 'text1'), 'string', str1)
```

If your function is initializing `textgui`, then you can pass the string directly to the GUI function as an input parameter:

```
str1 = 'my string';
textgui(str1);
```

This requires you to modify the `textgui_OpeningFcn` defined by GUIDE to process the input argument (stored in `varargin`):

```
function textgui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    set(handles.text1, 'String', varargin{1})

    % Leave the other stuff that GUIDE sets alone
end
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but my function `function1` is a different function from the GUI. `function1` will generate the string `str1`, and then call `textgui` to show the string in the static text.

Comment: @wesley Did you see my update where it doesn't require it to be part of the GUI? Also does `function` *create* the GUI?

Comment: @wesley Can you give some example code in your initial post to help demonstrate what you're referring to?

Comment: sure, I have edited with the code and an image of an example interface `textgui`. I have tried your code on the update but the static text doesn't seems to get the string.

Comment: @wesley You said `textgui` was the tag, but is that also the name of the GUIDE GUI? Also did you call the `set(..)` command after calling `textgui`?

Comment: yes, sorry for the misinformation, I did tried calling the `set()` comment (both before or after) calling `textgui` but the static text did not get the string `str1`.

Comment: @wesley Ok then you need to search for the tag `'text1'` instead. I've updated it.